# linq statement for "in"

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to write linq statement for this sql statement below:

```
select * from Table1 where Table1.Id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I have selection set in a array or list

What is the linq statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var IdList = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
var result = db.Table.Where(x => IdList.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Edit: According to your comment:

```
db.tPass.Where(p => p.date == DateTime.Now 
                 && IdList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(p.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you. i wrote that and this error has occured: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user1642860 Can you provide your code ?? what is the type of Id, is it string ?

Comment: Type of Id is integer.
my code is:

    var pass = p from db.tPass where p.date == DateTime.Now & IdList.Contains(p.Id)

Comment: @user1642860 I don't think it is integer.I have updated my answer, try using that query

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems to be solved. there is no syntax error

Comment: `HashSet<int>` here is pointless. It will be transformed to `IN` within `SQL` query anyway...